# How to use Task Scheduler to open an elevated Powershell window and run SFC and DISM in Windows 10

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have a scheduled Task where an Admin Command Prompt opens up and runs SFC and DISM. Here are the actions I entered in the "Action" tab of Task Scheduler:

**Program/script:** *%windir%\system32\cmd.exe*

**Add Arguments (optional)** */k Dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup&&sfc/scannow&&Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth&&sfc/scannow*

Below is the exported XML file from my scheduled task:

2015-08-13T22:47:14.859563
    RAT-COMPUTER\RAT
    Performs a complete system file check with SFC and DISM twice.
    \System File Check & Repair
  
  
    
      2015-08-17T12:00:00
      true
      
        
          
        
        1
      
    
  
  
    
      S-1-5-21-4275024122-2477020419-317910845-1001
      InteractiveToken
      HighestAvailable
    
  
  
    IgnoreNew
    false
    true
    true
    true
    true
    
      true
      false
    
    true
    true
    false
    false
    false
    true
    true
    PT72H
    7
    
      PT5M
      3
    
  
  
    
      %windir%\system32\cmd.exe
      /k Dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup&&sfc/scannow&&Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth&&sfc/scannow

I tried to run exactly the same scheduled task now on Powershell but with no luck. What do I need to do to "translate" this from command prompt into powershell in the Task Scheduler?

Comment: Why do you want to run this command through powershell rather than cmd? if you're not going to use powershell commands, there will be no gain into using powershell over command prompt.

Comment: Let's say an older (and supposedly wiser) relative of mine insists that Powershell is superior and will replace one day good ol' command prompt and also thinks tasks initated by powershell work faster.

Comment: I disagree with this. If one day powershell will replace command prompt, it will be in a different operating system, thus you'll need to recreate the task anyway. And powershell being faster than cmd? unlikely. Maybe if you actively use powershell commands vs regular commands, yes. but your script is not changing that.

Answer (score 1):

If it's working in cmd there isn't really any reason to switch to PowerShell but in case you eventually need to run a task in PowerShell:

**Program:** `%windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`

**Arguments:** `-command Dism /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup&&sfc/scannow&&Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth&&sfc/scannow`